# Add to Timeline vs Login

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've got or site working with timeline using the new javascript SDK sample code but we'd like to move this into the natural flow of the script for authenticated users [so they don't have to actively post items each time they do an action].

I suspect I'm over thinking this but will adding publish_actions to the existing login-button calls be enough to grant timeline permission or do we have to have to run the separate add-to-time feature shown in the new Open Graph tutorial [https://developers.facebook.com/docs/beta/authentication/]?

Comment: So sorry for not responding to this earlier. Sufficient to say we've used publish_actions in the existing login auth flow and it works just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding the `publish_actions` permission to the login-button call will suffice to publish Open Graph actions into Timeline.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to request and the user will have to approve the "publish_stream" permission.  This appears on a 2nd dialog advising the user that additional permissions are being requested.

Your app should be able to handle the user not providing this approval.

Comment: that's great info. we've coded it as an optional request... thank you